# Perl generate a file based on a template

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am working on a use case that requires me to generate .hpp files based on a template. So something like

```
#ifdef changethis_hpp
#define changethis_hpp

#include<fixedheader1>
...
#include<fixedheaderN>

class changethis
{
....
};
```

needs to be generated based on the requirement of `changethis` string.
How can I achieve this in perl?

**WHITSF**
I wrote a fixed template.txt file and and then replaced the text with `changethis` string and then dumped it as a changethis.hpp.

But is there any other way I can achieve this in perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Text::Template](http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template) for such tasks.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Perl FAQ, [How can I expand variables in text strings?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3F). It starts like this:

> If you can avoid it, don't, or if you can use a templating system,
>   such as [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Template) or [Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template) Toolkit, do that instead.
>   You might even be able to get the job done with `sprintf` or `printf`:
>
> ```
> my $string = sprintf 'Say hello to %s and %s', $foo, $bar;
> ```
>
> However, for the one-off simple case where I don't want to pull out a
>   full templating system, I'll use a string that has two Perl scalar
>   variables in it. In this example, I want to expand `$foo` and `$bar` to
>   their variable's values:
>
> ```
> my $foo = 'Fred';
> my $bar = 'Barney';
> $string = 'Say hello to $foo and $bar';
> ```
>
> One way I can do this involves the substitution operator and a double `/e` 
>   flag. The first `/e` evaluates `$1` on the replacement side and turns it 
>   into `$foo`. The second `/e` starts with `$foo` and replaces it with its 
>   value. `$foo`, then, turns into 'Fred', and that's finally what's left in 
>   the string:
>
> ```
> $string =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg; # 'Say hello to Fred and Barney'
> ```
>
> The `/e` will also silently ignore violations of strict, replacing 
>   undefined variable names with the empty string. Since I'm using the `/e`
>   flag (twice even!), I have all of the same security problems I have with
>   eval in its string form. If there's something odd in `$foo` , perhaps
>   something like `@{[ system "rm -rf /" ]}`, then I could get myself in
>   trouble.

I'd highly recommend you ignore most of this advice and go directly to a templating system (as recommended in the first line).